# Frustrating behavior for google modules/backends

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, backend

I'm working with GAE, and I'm trying to process a large zip file (~150mb zipped, 500 unzipped), which I need to do every day for my app.

I created a module to load a file from Google Cloud Storage, and parse through it, saving specific pieces of information in Google Datastore along the way. The problem is that it will shut itself down within a few minutes, and I basically lose where I am in the file. I am giving the instance more than enough CPU/memory, so that's not the issue..

Is there some way to handle this? The documentation for handling shutdowns is quite limited, and it seems shutdown requests aren't even guaranteed.. It seems really odd to me that GAE isn't able to handle a ~150mb file, nor can GAE guarantee 10-15 minutes of uptime at a time. Is there a way to get around these limitations? Thanks..

**EDIT:**

Why when I go to load my module ([modulename].[appname].appspot.com), it loads all available instances:

[image]

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing) states

"http://module.app-id.appspot.com
Send the request to an available instance of the default version of the named module (round robin scheduling is used)."

Answer (score 0):

Did you really measure that there is enough memory ?! If you load the 500Mb unzipped into memory, then that's a lot.

I have seen this behavior when running out of memory. I would suggest to try with a smaller test file. If that works, try to implement a streaming solution where the size of the file won't matter since it is never loaded into memory.